# GCC: blocks in assignments with return values making macros easier?

Tags: gcc, macros, gcc-extensions

I vaguely recall that GCC had an extension letting you write something like:

```
    total += { if ( b == answerb ) {
              printf( "b = %d (correct)\n", b );
              return 1;
          } else {
              printf( "b = %d (incorrect, answer was %d)\n", b, answerb );
              return 0;
        };
```

The code inside the outer braces would run, with the return value being assigned to `total`.

This existed (if it indeed existed) with the main intent that you could write the code to the right of that `=` in a macro that was similar to an inline function but also letting you do preprocessor tricks with the symbols such as using `#` and `##` on the macro arguments to construct variable names and strings from the macro parameters, which cannot be done with inline functions:

```
#define SCORE( test, correct ) \
    { if ( test == correct ) { \
              printf( #test "= %d (correct)\n", test ); \
              return 1; \
          } else { \
              printf( #test " = %d (incorrect, answer was %d)\n", test, correct ); \
              return 0; \
        };
total = 0;
total += SCORE( a, answera );
total += SCORE( b, answerb );
```

Does this actually exist?  If so, what is it called, so I can research it further?  How does it work?  And was it made part of the C/C++ standards?

Answer (score 1):

What about the following approach?

```
#define CHECK_ADD_SCORE( test, correct, total ) \
{ if ( test == correct ) { \
          printf( #test "= %d (correct)\n", test ); \
          total += 1; \
      } else { \
          printf( #test " = %d (incorrect, answer was %d)\n", test, correct ); \
};
total = 0;
CHECK_ADD_SCORE( a, answera, total );
CHECK_ADD_SCORE( b, answerb, total );
```

Comment: thx, achieves the aim of my example quite cleanly, but to be clear I was looking not for a clean or portable solution, but rather the NAME of a feature that allowed "return" statements like that....

Comment: @SwissFrank for such cases just use function, that returns value. `return 1;` and `return 0;` work for functions of type `int`. Do not waste time on macros